# How to select multiple cells in one specific column from a table

Tags: sql

```
                              TABLE
____________________________________________________________________

UID |               KEY                   |             VALUE             |
6              txtPaymentDate                    Shared Uderlying RSUS
6              txtTerminationReason1               Please Input Data
6              txtUnvestedTest                      Unvested RSUs
```

My goal is to SELECT Each VALUE to where it has it's own cell for the input of a report... For example.

```
SELECT VALUE as txtPaymentDate WHERE Key = 'txtPaymentdate', VALUE as txtTerminationReason1 WHERE key ='txtTerminationReason1'
```

ETC.... The end result I am looking for is to have all cells from the value column as their own column individually so I can input them in a telerik report using field inputs.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table is a typical unnormalized key-value store.  You may achieve what you want by aggregating on the `UID` column and the pivoting out the values, given each key:

```
SELECT
    UID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN "KEY" = 'txtPaymentDate'        THEN VALUE END) AS txtPaymentDate,
    MAX(CASE WHEN "KEY" = 'txtTerminationReason1' THEN VALUE END) AS txtTerminationReason1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN "KEY" = 'txtUnvestedTest'       THEN VALUE END) AS txtUnvestedTest
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    UID;
```

Note the `KEY` is usually a reserved keyword in most versions of SQL.  Hence, I placed your `KEY` column in double quotes.  You should avoid naming your database objects using keywords.

Comment: Works great. Thanks. One last question. Are unnormalized key-value stores common?

Comment: I see it used a lot in some of the standard Wordpress tables.  Yes, it comes up often, but the query in my answer tends to be expensive, so if you can normalize your data, then please do so.  One normalized version which might make sense would just maintain separate columns for the various text types.  But, this would not scale for an arbitrary number of different text types (hence your current design).